# BottomTab enabled in all screens

Tags: navigation, react-native, tabnavigator

I'm trying to make a "createBottomTabNavigator" always visible in all Screens.

However, this "BottomTabNavigator" is inside a "createDrawerNavigator" and the Bottomtab only show on the Screens associated to the Main "Stack" (the one I set to show as first. Every time I select another screen from the side menu the BottomTab disappear.

I already tried to set it to always visible in all stacks, without success, there is something that I could be missing?

Can I do this with the "createBottomTabNavigator" or I need to create my own FooterTab?

The next text is a representation of how my screens are connected ones to the others. Let me know if it's understandable, or do you need any more information.

- DrawerNavigator

  - BottomTabNavigator

    - Stack1

      - Screen1
      - Screen2
    - Stack3

      - Screen3
      - Screen4
    - Stack3

      - Screen5
      - Screen6
  - Stack3

    - Screen3
    - Screen4
  - Stack3

    - Screen5
    - Screen6

Thanks.